# Html comment breaking the website

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui, meteor, iron-router

I was getting a "Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node'" error after clicking a link to another page:

```
<template name="reminderPage">
    <a href="/newRemind">New!</a>
    {{>reminder}}
    <!-- Random comment -->
</template>

<template name="reminder" class="reminder">
      <p>Hello reminder</p>
        {{>editForm}}
</template>

<template name="editForm">
    <div id="dialog-form" title="Edit Reminder">
      <p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>
      <form>
        <fieldset>
          <label for="taskf-name">Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="taskf-name" id="taskf-name" maxlength="20">
          <label>Bought</label>
          <input type="text" name="taskf-bought" id="taskf-bought">
          <label>Expire</label>
          <input type="text" name="taskf-expire" id="taskf-expire">
        </fieldset>
      </form>
    </div>
</template>
```

Apparently, that little comment was interfering with the code because after I deleted it, everything worked perfectly.

While problem was fixed, I would really like to know how could this line be getting in the way of the code.

Does anyone know why? I was using Meteor with Iron-Router.

Thank you!

**EDIT**

If it helps, I am using Jquery-UI and this was my javascript file

```
Template.reminder.rendered = function () {

  $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    open: function () {
    },
    buttons: [
        {
          id: "button-ok",
          text: "Save",
          click: function() {
              $(this).dialog("close");
          }
        },
        {
          id: "button-cancel",
          text: "Cancel",
          click: function() {
              $(this).dialog("close");
          }
        }
    ]
  });

}
```

The "newRemind" page just has the most basic dialog, and it's js file just initiates it.

```
<template name="newRemindPage">
    <div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
      <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
    </div>
</template>
```

Javascript:

```
Template.newRemindPage.rendered = function () {
  $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
};
```

Comment: must be something with your Iron-Router, comments inside a template do not cause any side effects. Here's the proof: http://jsfiddle.net/b4f9wwt8/

Comment: Try using Spacebars comments instead of HTML comments : `{{!-- COMMENT --}}`

Comment: It's kinda weird. After more testing, what breaks the website is those dialogs. If I remove either, the comment can stay, but if keep both, the app crashes when the comment is present. 

Moreover, if I change the comment for anything that is not surrounded by tags (eg. a random text), the app crashes, but if I tag it, it works

Comment: Changing the comment for `hello` breaks the page, but `<p>hello</p>` does not. Spacebars comments also break it. @saimeunt

Answer (score 0):

Per [Spacebars documentation on comments](http://meteorcapture.com/spacebars/#comments):

```
{{! Comments can be one line}}

{{!
  Or they can be
  multi-line
}}

{{!-- They can also be written like this --}}
```

Please post your updated code if it doesn't work after trying this.

Comment: Replacing the comment by any of those still crashes the website. The only way they work (or the standard html comments) is if I surround them by a div.

`{{!-- They can also be written like this --}}` crashes.
`<div>{{!-- They can also be written like this --}}</div>` does not crash.

Comment: You might want to post an issue to the repo in case this is a bug: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues

Comment: Alright. I did not really want to post it because I think it's Jquery-ui's fault. The website has two dialogs (one on each page) and when either is removed, it works fine. 

Thanks a lot for your help, though!